# Restart remote servers with a Python script

Tags: python, restart, shutdown

I'm trying to write a Python script that will restart a series of servers on the same network in a specified sequence. I have used os.system('shutdown /r') to restart my own machine, but I cannot find the documentation to shutdown remote servers with usernames and passwords. I eventually want to run the Python script from a Raspberry Pi on the push of a button. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `/r` smells like Windows, which would complicate this a bit, is that the case?

Comment: yes the remote servers are running windows.

Answer (score 4):

This article explains in detail how to configure remote shutdown for Windows: http://www.howtogeek.com/109655/how-to-remotely-shut-down-or-restart-windows-pcs/

Note that you will need [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) to get a `net` command which you can run from Linux.

If that is no available, then the workaround is to write a small server in Python which you install on a Windows box which accepts the "restart everything" command from the Pi (use a plain socket server but implement some kind of password protection).

Answer (score 2):

If you can access those servers through SSH, try [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/)

Very useful tool!

Comment: i thought the same, but task is to restart Windows remote host. I suppose one could set up ssh server on windows machine and connect with fabric, but have you ever tried something like this?

Comment: That is what I though too. Looking to Fabric's changelog seems to have Windows support -> http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/changelog.html?highlight=windows but I have never tested it. Also looking to Fabric's mail archive, people are using it with Win servers... so I think you can :)